# Converting date string to "Weekday, Month, Date, Year" format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, d3.js

I'm trying to convert date formats in d3.js Here's my code, using d3.js (the dates are being accessed on mouseover of points on the map):

```
d3.selectAll(".events")
      .on("mouseover", function(d) { 
        console.log(d.startDate)
}
```

Which is giving me output such as:

```
2019-02-23
```

I want it to read Saturday February 23 2019.  When I try:

```
d3.selectAll(".events")
      .on("mouseover", function(d) { 
        var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
        console.log(d.startDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options)) 
}
```

I get an error saying:

```
d.startDate.toLocaleDateString is not a function
at SVGCircleElement
```

Curious what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: There are thousands of ways to format a date in various ways. There is already a duplicate that contains the most used formats, just take one that is very close and apply some small changes, then you should get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help all.  toLocaleDateString() is definitely what I want - thank you.  I can't quite get it to work in reading d.startDate in my date, to convert it.  It is not recognizing .toLocaleDateString() as a function and not sure why.

Comment: Maybe it is not a date but a string? Then convert it to a date `new Date("2019-02-23").toLocaleString()`

Comment: Jonas, thanks, I think the issue is trying to get new Date to read in d.startDate (i.e. the 'date' property in my data).  When I try:   console.log(new Date(d.startDate).toLocaleDateString("en-US", options))  , it just outputs today's date when I hover over every point .  So it's working, but it's not reading in the actual date associated with the data.  Does that make sense?